# First order ODE: $2tx'-x=\ln x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$2tx'-x=\ln x$$

First I differentiated both sides with respect to $t$
$$2x'+2tx''-\frac{x''}{x'}=x'$$
Then substituted $p=x'$ and changed it a bit
$$p^2+2tpp'=p'$$
But I dont know what should I do from here on. Should I differentiate it again?

Comment: I made a mistake in this equation. Right hand side should be $\ln x'$ instead of $\ln x$

Comment: Please do not modify substantially the question after some answer is posted.

Answer (score 2):

This is $tx'(t)=F(x(t))$ with $F:u\mapsto \tfrac12u+\tfrac12\log u$ hence $$\frac{x'}{F(x)}=\frac1t,$$ that is, for some $t_0$, $$\int_{x(t_0)}^{x(t)}\frac{\mathrm du}{F(u)}=\log\left(\frac{t}{t_0}\right).$$ One can rewrite this as $$x(t)=G^{-1}\left(G(x(t_0))+\log\left(\frac{t}{t_0}\right)\right),$$ where $G$ is some primitive of the function $1/F$ and $G^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $G$. Whether one can makes this more explicit depends on the specific function $G$ involved.

In the present case, $G$ has no expression in terms of standard mathematical functions but a qualitative analysis is as follows. Call $x^*$ the unique solution of the equation $x^*+\log x^*=0$ (thus, $x^*=\mathrm e^{-W(1)}\approx0.567$). Then, for every $x(t_0)\gt x^*$ and every $t_0$, the function $x(\ )$ is defined on the whole real line, increasing, with limits $+\infty$ and $x^*$ when $t\to+\infty$ and $t\to-\infty$ respectively.